# After throwing in AOP

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I've got a custom exception called "LoginException". It might be thrown from any class. So I want to make an advice to do something(for example, print "Ooops") after throwing. So I decided to use AOP. Something like this:

```
@Aspect
public class LogoutAdvice {

    @AfterThrowing(throwing = "e")
    public void myAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, LoginException e) {    
        System.out.println("IDS HABBENING");
    }
}
```

Code:

```
@Transactional
    public DynamicTable getTable(int status_id, HttpServletRequest request)
            throws HibernateException, LoginException, SQLException {
        try {
            ResultSet rs = requestDAO.getRequestResultSet(
                    cookieDAO.get(SESS_ATTR, request), status_id);
            DynamicTable dt = new DynamicTable();
            String[] columnArray;
            LinkedList<String[]> dataList = new LinkedList<String[]>();
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            columnArray = new String[columnCount - META_COLUMNS_COUNT];
            for (int i = 0; i < columnArray.length; i++) {
                columnArray[i] = rsmd.getColumnName(META_COLUMNS_COUNT + i + 1);
            }
            dt.setTitleArray(columnArray);

            while (rs.next()) {

                String[] dataArray = new String[columnArray.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < columnArray.length; i++) {
                    dataArray[i] = ParamUtil.toString(rs
                            .getObject(META_COLUMNS_COUNT + i + 1));
                }

                dataList.add(dataArray);

            }
            dt.setDataList(dataList);

            return dt;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            String message = e.getMessage();
            String[] errorsArray = AuthErrorsConst.ERROR;
            for (int i = 0; i < errorsArray.length; i++) {
                if (message.contains(errorsArray[i])) {
                    throw new LoginException(); // LOOK AT THIS

                }
            }
            throw e;
        }

    }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Is there an error in what you are doing? If so, please share details of what is not behaving as you expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be sure the exception is being thrown

```
catch (SQLException e) {
      String message = e.getMessage();
      String[] errorsArray = AuthErrorsConst.ERROR;
      for (int i = 0; i < errorsArray.length; i++) {
          if (message.contains(errorsArray[i])) {
              System.out.println("throwing LoginException")// NEW
              throw new LoginException(); // LOOK AT THIS
          }
      }
      throw e;
}
```

About

```
@Aspect
public class LogoutAdvice {

    @AfterThrowing(throwing = "e")
    public void myAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, LoginException e) {    
        System.out.println("IDS HABBENING");
    }
}
```

**Be sure** Spring has enable to work with `@Aspect` and **furthermore** it be able to scan your `LogoutAdvice` aspect, normally I declare them how

```
@Aspect
@Component// to be scanned by Spring
public class LogoutAdvice {
```

Change your `@AfterThrowing` to

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* *.*(..))",throwing = "e")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a point cut in your `@AfterThrowing` annotation

Therefore your annotation will need to look something like below

`@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(public * *(..))",throwing = "e")`

Please refer to below link for elaborate explanation:

http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/05/spring-aop-after-throwing-advice.html#.VCAnsvmSw2c

Comment: Should I bean LogoutAdvice?

Comment: Do you mean create bean for LogoutAdvice?

Comment: No you don't need to create bean for that, annotation will take care of it.

Comment: Bad news. No massage after throwing.

Comment: Can you share the code from where your throwing exception?

Comment: Look. Ctrl + F "LOOK AT THIS".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61689/discussion-between-mangesh-jogade-and-tony).

Answer (score 0):

1) Check you `LoginException` class as it should be a proper exception class.

2) throw the exception object "e" in catch block

3)

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LogoutAdvice {
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution (* * com..*(..)", throwing = "e")
    public void myAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, LoginException e) {    
        System.out.println("IDS HABBENING");
    }
}
```

4) in spring configuration file

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

thats enough.